# Use MangoDb in android applications

Tags: android, mongodb

I am trying to use MongoDB in my application as this DB is good for performance issues

I read some answers but they were not clear like

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.0.3'
}
```

Dependancy is given but nothing is mentioned after that, how to use that and all

https://insights.nimblechapps.com/app-development/android-app-development/using-mongodb-storing-retrieving-data-android

In this tutorial, a concept is explained as we can directly access the DB by the URL and store and retrieve data from it

I followed that tutorial but I am not able to create an account for mangolab

Can anyone know about this and if you have done realtime, what are the difficulties you faced, Please provide me with all this information so that it will help me to make a decision

And if any of the apps use this DB let me know the play store links of the app so that I will go through that and get some idea

Please help me with this

Thank you all in advance

Comment: MongoDB has no HTTP interface, and you certainly don’t want to expose a public MongoDB to the internet. You need an API server to accept and validate HTTP requests and insert the data into MongoDB. MongoLab is one such service which does that, or you write your own.

Comment: Is there any android app which uses the MongoDB without API, Do they directly insert and fetch data from MongoDB without web services

Comment: I don’t know if there “is any”; it certainly wouldn’t seem like a good idea.

Comment: Read [this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/)

Comment: Parse-server is a good option as well (in my opinion at least). You can quickly get a free setup with parse-server hosted on Heroku and an mLab sandbox https://parseplatform.org/